# No module named numpy

Tags: python

```
porco1 =    [1,1,0]
porco2 =    [1,1,0]
porco3 =    [1,1,0]
cachorro1 = [1,1,1]
cachorro2 = [0,1,1]
cachorro3 = [0,1,1]

dados = [porco1, porco2, porco3, cachorro1, cachorro2, cachorro3]

marcacoes = [1, 1, 1, -1, -1, -1]

misterioso = [1, 1, 1]

from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB

modelo = MultinomialNB()
modelo.fit(dados, marcacoes)
print(ntmodelo.predict(misterioso))
```

Estou tentando rodar este código em Python, mas sempre aparece este erro. Alguém pode me ajudar, por favor
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Pela mensagem, parece que a biblioteca `numpy` não está instalada. Tente executar  o comando `python -m pip install numpy` ou `pip install numpy`

Comment: Ao invés de postar uma foto do erro faça a seleção e copie e cole aqui, fotos de códigos e erros nem sempre são uteis

Answer (score 3):

Você precisa instalar o `NumPy`.

Se você já tiver o `pip` instalado, basta rodar o seguinte comando:

```
pip install numpy
```

Se não possuir o `pip` instalado ainda, você precisa fazer o download do [get-pip.py](https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py).

Em seguida, você precisa executar o arquivo que você acabou de baixar.

Exemplo:

```
python get-pip.py
```